# Android Retrofit sending email with attachment using mailgun

Tags: android, email, retrofit, mailgun

I am using retrofit and mailgun to send email. I am able to successfully send email with the code I have.

Now I do not know how to add attachment to the mail.

Here is my code :

```
    private SendMailApi sendMailApi;

public interface SendMailApi {

    @Headers({ACCEPT_JSON_HEADER})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/messages")
    void authUser(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
            @Field("from") String from,
            @Field("to") String to,
            @Field("subject") String subject,
            @Field("text") String text,
            Callback<MailGunResponse> cb
    );
}

public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String msg, Callback<MailGunResponse> cb){
    String from = "test <test@address.com>";
    String clientIdAndSecret = "api" + ":" + "key-*******";
    String authorizationHeader = BASIC + " " + Base64.encodeToString(clientIdAndSecret.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    sendMailApi.authUser(authorizationHeader,from, to, subject, msg, cb);
}

public MailGun() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = getAuthAdapter();
    sendMailApi = restAdapter.create(SendMailApi.class);
}

private RestAdapter getAuthAdapter(){
    RestAdapter.LogLevel logLevel = RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL;
    if(DEBUG)logLevel = RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL;
    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))
            .setLogLevel(logLevel)
            .build();
}
```

Now I have no idea where and at what field attachment should go.
Please give me an example, like attaching an image when I have its path.

Remember that I am able to send email successfully right now without attachments.

Thank you very much

Comment: Haven't tried this mysleft, but according to the docs, attachments use multipart to send. I don't know if this will work with retrofit though, there's an issue about it [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/662)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to send an attachment. People found a way in issues [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1140) and [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063). It looks very ugly and could probably break later, but works on retorfit 2.0.0.

```
@Multipart
@POST("messages")
Observable<Void> send(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
        @Part("from") RequestBody from,
        @Part("to") RequestBody to,
        @Part("subject") RequestBody subject,
        @Part("text") RequestBody text,
        @Part("recipient-variables") RequestBody variables,
        @Part("attachment\"; filename=\"image.jpg") RequestBody attachment
    );


request = mailgun.send(
        MailGun.AUTH,
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "from"),
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "to"),
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "subject"),
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "message"),
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "{}"),
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), byteArray)
);
```

Check `RequestBody.create()` for other methods of loading an image, but all should work for this. I don't know about `text/plain`, but I could not open the image without `image/*`.

Comment: Hi, I need to do the same, use mailgun with an attachment. Could you help posting the entire code please?

Comment: Can't really add anything. Keep in mind, that this post is 3 years old and I haven't done any mailgun work since.